What is the formula for the given values? 4th difference is alternating between positive and negative.
The given values are:



x
y




1
80


2
260


3
640


4
1240


5
2160


6
3420


7
5120



It is obviously not a linear equation, but it quite complex.
I was thinking that maybe it is some sort of special summation, but I am not sure how I would construct it. I broke down the differences, and the 4th difference was alternating between -80 and +80. This led me to believe that it includes -1^x power or maybe a trigonometric function.



x
y
Δ1
Δ2
Δ3
Δ4




1
80






2
260
+180





3
640
+380
+200




4
1240
+600
+220
+20



5
2160
+920
+320
+100
+80


6
3420
+1260
+340
+20
-80


7
5120
+1700
+440
+100
+80



Using this, it is easy to determine the next values, but the formula seems impossible for to come up with. I could use coding to get the value for basically any number, but I would prefer a specific formula.
This is my first post, so I apologize if I am not following standards. Thank you for your time.

Are you trying to find an interpolating polynomial?

@SeanRoberson I am not completely sure what type of function it is, and that is part of what I am trying to figure out

A very, very strong hint for you: plot the points first, and observe that the $y$ values grow really, really fast.

Recommend: Conway and Guy, The Book of Numbers

Jackson's Difference Fans are pages 84-86

Thank you guys, but this is not for a school project or anything. This is me trying to reverse engineer some numbers from a video game.

The first nonzero value in each column of the difference table suggests the following formula:
$$
80\binom{x-1}{0}+180\binom{x-1}{1}+200\binom{x-1}{2}+20\binom{x-1}{3}+\sum_{k=4}^\infty 80(-2)^{k-4} \binom{x-1}{k},
$$
which simplifies to
$$10 x^3 + 30 x^2 + 30 x + 5 - 5 (-1)^x.$$
As suggested by https://oeis.org/A301647, you can also express this as
$$10\left((x+1)^3-((x+1)\pmod 2)\right).$$

Thank you a lot, and I would also love to understand why this is the case

See this: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Finite_difference#Newton's_series and a few more examples (with the rows and columns reversed) here: https://math.stackexchange.com/search?q=user%3A683666+%22difference+table%22

It is also equal to $20\lfloor(x+1)^3 / 2\rfloor$, which is slightly more compact.
